# how do i install a nodejs app in cpanel but there is no setup nodejs in my cpanel software part

Tags: node.js

i want install a node.js app in cpanel and i have searched in google and all articles say that there is a setup node.js option in software part but there is no Setup nod.js option in my cpanel software part ,
and when i send a ticket to host support they reply that node.js is installed by default now i want to know how can i install a node.js app without setup node.js option .

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```